Why doesn't a button switch the scene like it's supposed to?
I'm creating an options menu into my game and everything works except the button that is supposed to take back to the menu doesn't work. i can't even click it despite it being set up as usual and enabled. All the scenes are set up correctly too, i think. It's not even that it doesn't do anything but clicks, it doesn't click. it acts like it would not be a button, just a color rect or something.
extends Control

func _on_Button_pressed():
    get_tree().change_scene("res://scenes/scenes/menu.tscn")

func _on_master_value_changed(value):
    adjust_volume("Master", value)

func _on_music_value_changed(value):
    adjust_volume("Music", value)

func _on_sfx_value_changed(value):
    adjust_volume("SFX", value)
    
func adjust_volume(bus_name: String, linear_value: float):
    var db_value = linear2db(linear_value)
    AudioServer.set_bus_volume_db(AudioServer.get_bus_index(bus_name), db_value)
    
func linear2db(linear_value: float) -> float:
    if linear_value == 0:
        return -80.0
    else:
        var t = linear_value / 100.0
        return 20.0 * log(t) / log(10.0) 

I tried making a new button and setting it up again but it doesn't do anything. I also checked if all the scenes are okay and it seems to be so.

What error do you get, if any? Did you try to put a print statement into the function to see if it is called? change_scene is nonexistent in the normal SceneTree, so if called it should print an error normally.

"The function 'change_scene()' returns a value, but this value is never used."

OK, so the tag godot4 is wrong? Are you on an godot version 3.x? There the function exists and returns an error, if something went wrong. See: https://docs.godotengine.org/de/3.x/classes/class_scenetree.html#class-scenetree-method-change-scene

oh, okay. the tag is actually wrong, i thought i had a different version. it's godot 3.5 if i'm looking at the correct place to check it. it says 3.5.stable

Nonetheless, since I am not sure what you tried now: Add print("button pressed") before the line, that should switch scenes. This should be printing the message into your console, when pushing the button to make sure this part works. Then change the next line to:
var err = get_tree().change_scene("res://scenes/scenes/menu.tscn") and then print out the code with print(err) aswell. Error Codes can be found here: https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_%40globalscope.html#class-globalscope-constant-err-cant-open . This might give us a clue where to find the error.

i did that right now and the previous message disappeared but nothing is printed either.
func _on_Button_pressed():  var err = get_tree().change_scene("res://scenes/scenes/menu.tscn")  print(err)

Seems like we have to check you connected signals and button settings. You could upload the scene to github to have a look, or edit your question and add more images of the button settings, connected signals and scene tree

link to github: https://github.com/c0ff334dd1ct/button
i added screenshots of the signals and settings of the button.

The link is not accessable

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

After looking at the images and discussing the problem via chat, we found the reason, why it was not working.
For context, the scene tree looked like this:
Root
   BgImage
   Button
   Audio # Some Containers to hold slider and stuff

In his scene the Audio Containers are above the button and the button was near the bottom of the view.
The configuration of the signal was set up correctly.
What was causing the error was, that some parts of the audio container, which are invisible, were overlapping with the button. Since the button was below the Audio Containers, the click commands got caught by the container and never reached the button.
After putting the button after the Audio Containers in the scene tree, it worked as excepted.

Maybe you need to change
get_tree().change_scene("res://scenes/scenes/menu.tscn")

To
get_tree().change_scene("res://scenes//menu.tscn")

Check if button can be clicked.
Add print("smth") in _on_Button_pressed() function to check it
edit. Check if button_pressed_func is linked with your script
